# Action mailer working with deliver but not with delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

When I use the deliver method like below my action mailer work just fine and send email

```
GroupInvitationMailer.send_invitation_to_contacts(invited_user, current_user, @group).deliver
```

But when I use delayed job this method "send_invitation_to_contacts" do not even get called as I can see by debugging but the invited member is added to group. Only mail is not sent to the invited use.

```
GroupInvitationMailer.delay.send_invitation_to_contacts(invited_user, current_user, @group)
```

I googled this and found some solution but they are not working for me. I tried

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'   this use version 3.0.0
```

and also I tried

```
gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.2'
```

none of this work for me.

Comment: when you use delayed_job gem, what is present in schedule.rb, hav u updated your crontab, provide the o/p crontab -i

Comment: This is my schedule.rb file
'job_type :rake, "source '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm' && cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output"

set :output, 'log/cron.log'

every :day, :at => '12:01 am' do
  rake 'generate_tasks:all'
end'

Comment: are you able to send other mails, check for the smtp mailer settings in the environment files. Refer logs to look for if the mail template is being created. Check the to and from in the template created